# C: Fill array only with the size of scanfed string

Tags: c

After i put a name in the terminal and it is shorter, then 20 chars, it wants inputs until i have filled all the 20 positions in the array.
I know it is because of the for cycle i have there, but I don't know how else to fill that end of the array with nothing("").
In the array there is for example this "Helloworld\n123\n123"
Thank you for help in advance.

```
#define NAME 20
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
 
main(void) {
    char name[NAME] = {""};
    malloc(sizeof(name[NAME]));

    printf("Choose your name: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < NAME; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &name[i]);
    }

    //Welcome and the name
    printf("Welcome: "); 
    for (int i = 0; i < NAME; i++) {
        printf("%c", name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(x)` without storing the value returned is completely pointless.  It has the side effect of generating a memory leak, but otherwise does nothing.  What are you trying to do with that `malloc`?

Comment: This sounds like [strncpy](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html), which fills the string with zeros intended to be used with non-zero terminated fixed strings.

Comment: Vít Hromek, `"Helloworld\n123\n123"` is 18 characters and then a _null character_.  That requires an array of _at least 19 `char`.  Do you consider `'\n'` part of the name? or is the name only `"HelloWorld"`?

Comment: Yup, that malloc is pointless. :D

It is really not that much important for me, if it is or it isn't part of the name. The important for me is what is shown. I don't really need exact lenght, but if i will ever need that, I will add that to the lenght then. 

Many thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for answering. Unfortunately the first two answers are too complicated for me yet. And the third one was not working properly.

But I found the simplest answer. :) Many thanks

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 
    char name[20]; 
    printf("Choose your name: "); 
    scanf("%[^\n]*c",name); 
     
    printf("My name is %s",name); 
     
}
```

Comment: This answer is not safe: if the user enters more than 15 characters on the input line, the behavior is undefined and the newline will be left in the input stream. Furthermore, `scanf()` will fail and leave the `name` unchanged if the user hits the enter key without a name.

Comment: Agree, that it is not safe, but this question has only a purpose of stopping scanf after Enter. I am trying to keep the code as simple as possible, that is why i am showing only the important part of the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop reading at a newline (+should also check return codes).

A loop like:

```
    size_t i=0;
    for (; i < sizeof(name)-1; i++) {
        if (1==(scanf("%c",&name[i]))){ if (name[i]=='\n') break; }
        else if (feof(stdin)) break; //end of file?
        else return perror("getchar"),1; //report error
    }
    name[i]='\0';
```

will achieve that (can also use getchar/getc/fgetc instead of scanf)
or you can use fgets:

```
    if(NULL==fgets(name,sizeof(name),stdin)) return perror("fgets"),1;
    //erase a possibly included newline at the end
    //(won't be there if you pressed Ctrl+D twice rather than
    //Enter to submit your input or if you're at the end of 
    //a stdin redirected from a file)
    size_t len = strlen(name);
    if(name[len-1]=='\n') name[len-1]='\0';
```

Whole program with both versions (in the `if(0){...}else{...}`) :

```
#define NAME 20
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main(void) {
    char name[NAME] = {""};
    //malloc(sizeof(name[NAME])); //a useless memory leak; don't do this!

    printf("Choose your name: ");
    if(0){
        if(NULL==fgets(name,sizeof(name),stdin)) return perror("fgets"),1;
        size_t len = strlen(name);
        if(name[len-1]=='\n') name[len-1]='\0';
    }else{
        size_t i=0;
        for (; i < sizeof(name)-1; i++) {
            if (1==(scanf("%c",&name[i]))){ if (name[i]=='\n') break; }
            else if (feof(stdin)) break; //end of file?
            else return perror("getchar"),1;
        }
        name[i]='\0';
    }

    //Welcome and the name
    printf("Welcome: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < NAME; i++) {
        printf("%c", name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would not program in main only show the OP how to use functions forsimilar tasks

Comment: gcc optimizes out the function call when you do not use the result of maslloc

Comment: @0___________ Thanks. I wasn't trying to showcase ideal program structure (that would, for me, involve not using stdio at all) just the logic of what needs to be done with stdio. As for #2, I don't know what's more questionable: such a nonsensical use of malloc or the GCC optimization. :D (Personally not a fan of compilers specialcasing libc functions.)

Comment: Second was only as observation, which I tried only for the curiosity

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use scanf and `%c` format:

```
char *readLineUsingCharAndScanf(char *buff, size_t size, FILE *fi)
{
    char ch;
    char *wrk = buff;
    while(size-- && fscanf(fi, "%c", &ch) == 1 && ch != '\n' ) *wrk++ = ch;
    *wrk = 0;
    return buff;
}

void dumpString(const char *restrict str, size_t size)
{
    while(*str && size--)
    {
        printf("%03d [0x%02x] - %s\n", *str, *str, (*str >= 32 & *str <= 127) ? (char[]){'\'', *str, '\'', 0} : "not printable");
        str++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char name[20];

    dumpString(readLineUsingCharAndScanf(name, 19, stdin), 20);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vWvP68TbW

Comment: Hmmm, also I think you want `--size` to make space for the _null character_.  ( `readLineUsingCharAndScanf(buff, 0, fi)` as a pathologically case.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am consistent with %xs scanf format

Comment: `size--` allows `*wrk++ = ch` to execute 20 time with the following `*wrk = 0;` attempting to write to `name[20]`, which is UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica my bad, it should be 19. same as %19s for 20 chars buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` is not the best tool for your purpose. Here is a simple and safe solution:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define NAME 20

int main(void) {
    char name[NAME];
    int c;
    size_t i;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (i < sizeof(name) - 1)
            name[i++] = c;
    }
    name[i] = '\0';

    //Welcome and the name
    printf("Welcome: %s\n", name); 

    return 0;
}
```

If you **must** use `scanf()`, use this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define NAME 20

int main(void) {
    char name[NAME];
    char c;
    size_t i;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    i = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &c) == 1 && c != '\n') {
        if (i < sizeof(name) - 1)
            name[i++] = c;
    }
    name[i] = '\0';

    //Welcome and the name
    printf("Welcome: %s\n", name); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For your needs I would use `scanf` with the string conversion specifier `%s`. In this case, the input name would be read and stored character by character in the buffer  until the whitespace would be read. Here is the code.

```
#define NAME 20
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[NAME] = {""};
    malloc(sizeof(name[NAME]));
    printf("Choose your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("%s", &name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",...)` is like `gets`. There's no bound check. It allows longer user input to corrupt your program.